# Rasterize only fully contained fields

Tags: python, gdal

I have a shapefile with many polygons that are bigger than my working extent. I want to rasterize only fields that are fully contained in my working extent.

How can I do this?

Comment: By using your working extent, in -te gdal_rasterize option, as follow: `-te xmin ymin xmax ymax`.

Comment: And then, how do I deal with edge cases, i.e. fields that intersect the edges of the te?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by following this approach:

0 get extent of raster

1 rasterize polygons with raster extent (including edge polygons )

2 make geometry (ogr.wkbLineString) with extent of raster

3 create inmem temp shapefile

4 loop over features in fields shapefile and use geom.Intersects(ft.GetGeometryRef()) to select fields and add these features to inmem temp shapefile

5 rasterize inmem shapefile in rasterized fields with burnValues=0

code:

```
import ogr 
import osr
import gdal
from uuid import uuid4

all_touched = True
outputtype = gdal.GDT_UInt32
fn = "/some/small/raster.tif"
shp = "/some/big/vector.shp"

attribute = 'FID'
# 0 get extent of raster
ds0 = gdal.Open(fn)
gt, xsize, ysize = ds0.GetGeoTransform(), ds0.RasterXSize, ds0.RasterYSize
xmin, ymax = gt[0], gt[3]
xmax = gt[0] + gt[1] * xsize
ymin = gt[3] + gt[5] * xsize
te = [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]
spatref = osr.SpatialReference()
spatref.ImportFromWkt(ds0.GetProjection())
ds0 = None

# 1 rasterize big shape with raster extent (including edge polygons)
bigshpgrid = "/gridded/vector/with/extent/of/raster.tif"

ds1 = gdal.Rasterize(bigshpgrid, shp, outputBounds=te, xRes=gt[1], yRes=gt[5],
                    attribute=attribute, creationOptions=['COMPRESS=LZW'], 
                    allTouched=all_touched, outputType=outputtype)

# 2 make geometry object with extent of raster
ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString) 
ring.AddPoint(xmin, ymin)
ring.AddPoint(xmin, ymax)
ring.AddPoint(xmax, ymax)
ring.AddPoint(xmax, ymin)
ring.CloseRings()
# 3 create inmem temp shapefile
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('MEMORY')
tmpshpfn = uuid4().hex
tmpds = driver.CreateDataSource(tmpshpfn)
tmplyr = tmpds.CreateLayer(tmpshpfn, srs=spatref, geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)

# 4 loop over features in initial shapefile and save intersections with ring to tmplyr
dsshp = ogr.Open(shp)
lyrshp = dsshp.GetLayer(0)

ft = lyrshp.GetNextFeature()
while ft:
    geom = ft.GetGeometryRef()
    if ring.Intersects(geom):
        tmplyr.CreateFeature(ft.Clone())
    ft = lyrshp.GetNextFeature()
dsshp, lyrshp = None, None
# 5 Rasterize inmem layer to gridded vector of step 1
ds5 = gdal.RasterizeLayer(ds1, [1], tmplyr, burn_values=[0], options = ['ALL_TOUCHED={}'.format(str(all_touched))])
ds5 = None

ds1 = None
tmpds, tmplyr = None, None
ring = None
```